# Counting number of circular seating arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Here is the question:
How many ways are there to arrange a group of $10$ people into $2$ circles of $5$ people each? Note that in each circle, rotations are considered the same.

This is my attempt at answering the question, which I believe to be incorrect:
First, the number of ways we can get $2$ distinct groups of $5$ people from a set of 10 people is $C(10,5) = \frac{10!}{5!\cdot 5!} = 252$. Now, for each way of getting the 2 groups, the people can be arranged in $\frac{5!}{5} = 4! = 24$ ways. Thus, the answer is $252\cdot 24=6048$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer to Robert's is

$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{10!}{5\times 5}=72576
$$

Tell the people to stand in line ($10!$ ways), then the first $5$ go to the first circle and the rest go to the second circle. For each circle, divide by $5$ to eliminate rotations. The multiplication by $0.5$ is done if the two circles are unordered i.e. indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the circles are indistinguishable (meaning switching everyone's table assignment results in an arrangement that's considered the same), you've double-counted.  There are $\binom{10}{5}$ ways to choose a $5$-subset from a $10$-set.  However, choosing either a set or its complement results in the same collection of people in the two circles.

In other words, choosing $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ results in the same collection of two circles as choosing $\{6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$, because if you choose $\{6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$ for one table, the other table will automatically get $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$.  Also, each arrangement of people seated at one table must be paired with $24$ different arrangements of people at the other table.  So the correct answer is $126 \cdot 24^2 = 72576$.

Comment: Why did you only count the circular permutation of one table?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Because I made a mistake.  You're correct, and I'll edit my answer.